# How do I make this command read the password from standard input on terminal?

Tags: virtualbox, password, headless

Supposing this is how my Oracle VirtualBox machines are being started:

```
VBoxManage startvm "vmname" --type headless

VBoxManage controlvm "vmname" addencpassword "vmname" "/home/user/vm-name-password"
```

How do I make the command read the password from standard input on terminal?

Rationale: For security reasons I don't want those passwords stored on the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After running:

```
VBoxManage startvm "vmname" --type headless
```

The following command should ask for the password:

```
VBoxManage controlvm "vmname" addencpassword "identifier" -
```

The command uses the identifier visible to the left of the password entry textbox when you start the guest normally with a window. The hyphen at the end causes the request for the password in the command window.